# Remove previous version (Tokyo) before installing Rio?

Tags: delphi, installation

Having searched several sites (perhaps missing the one), I can't seem to find an answer to some questions concerning upgrading to Delphi 10.3 Rio. I hope that because of their relation, they can be accepted as a single question.

I have a subscription licenses and wish to update Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo to Delphi 10.3 Rio.  In principle I have no further use for Tokyo, so my questions are;

1. Should I manually uninstall Tokyo or will the installer (optionally) take care of this?
2. If I uninstall manually, before installing, will the subscription license be retained?
3. Should I uninstall Tokyo after installing Rio, could this lead to issues (e.g. "shared" files removed)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you uninstall? Keep them both in case you need to debug behaviour changes.

Comment: That sounds sensible but I just read in the installation notes (docWiki) that projects opened in 10.3 will be upgraded and "can no longer be opened in previous versions".

Comment: I don't know about these two versions specifically, but in general: 1. You can overwrite it, if you like, or install side by side, so basically: whichever you like best. 2. I think you have to enter the license key again on installation anyway. If you bought an upgrade, then the upgrade is not valid without the key it's upgrading from. You can not legally pass on the original license. 3. Uninstalling _might_ work, but I wouldn't risk it. Installing an older version after a newer almost certainly breaks the newer version.

Comment: @Golez Installing older version doesn't break the new version.

Comment: @Mark You are using revision control I presume, so you can go back if you need.

Comment: @David Actually I don't. Have been struggling to get it setup for my situation. Will post a separate question on that subject soon.

Comment: @Mark Well, I wouldn't be trying to do anything until you sort that out.

Comment: "can no longer be opened in previous versions" Sure, that applies with Firemonkey projects, but in my experience, VCL or non-framework-specific projects don't have any problem in downgrading. Unless of course you ended up using newly released features.

Comment: I had 10.2 on my machine. Then installed 10.3 parallel. License information was not requested again.

Comment: @Mark: that (i.e. that projects opened in Rio may not work in previous versions anymore) may be what the docs say, but I often try my projects in XE2 up to Rio and they just work.

Comment: @David: don't know if that is still the case, but if you installed an older version *after* a newer version, it could grab the file extensions. I guess you'll simply have to disable that part during the installation setup.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You can disable them, or you can just do a repair on the version that you wish to be your primary Delphi. And this is an important point. In my professional life XE7 is the primary Delphi. I have later versions installed, but that doesn't mean that the I need the latest version to be the primary version.

Answer (score 1):

*Should I manually uninstall Tokyo or will the installer (optionally) take care of this?*
I didn't and, unless you have dsik space issues, you shouldn't need to either.

*If I uninstall manually, before installing, will the subscription license be retained?*
Yes. You may need to re-enter your EDN creds (you shouldn't need to do this if you don't uninsdtall) but your licence allows you to use the version you originally bought, all the way up to the latest that was released when your subscription was valid.

*Should I uninstall Tokyo after installing Rio, could this lead to issues (e.g. "shared" files removed)?*
Possible, though it would most likeley affect components, especially those where you got a later version through the GetIt package manager. As long as you still have the installers for Rio though, you should be OK.